# Exception in Runnable not caught, and Executor will hang

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using a FixedThreadPool to run many threads. The methods doJobs() sometimes throws a runtime exception whose stacktrace is printed on the console but is not logged. It means that this exception is not caught in the `catch(Throwable)` in `MyRunnable`. The main problem is that after this exception, the Executor will stop executing any threads already submitted, and the whole application will just hang. How is it possible that this exception is not logged? Also, why the whole executor does not continue and does not finish but just hangs with no activity?

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() { 
        try {
            doJob();
        }
        catch(Error e){ log(e);}
        catch(Throwable e) {log(e);}
    }
}

//main method
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
for (final MyRunnable wc : runnables) {
    executor.execute(wc);
}
try {
    executor.awaitTermination(maxTime, TimeUnit.HOURS);
} catch (final InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: Would need to see the code of `doJob`.  It is probably writing its own stacktrace to the console and terminating, vs. bubbling the exception up to the `doJob` call where you can catch it.

Comment: some code of some lib I use will throw a runtime exception. Why is it not caught in the catch? How I should bubble it up the excpetion that are caught?

Comment: If it is actually throwing a RuntimeException, it is a subclass of Throwable - and you would catch it here.  More than likely, it is catching and outputting the stack trace of a RuntimeException itself - and not bubbling it up.  Unless it provides for a configuration, hook, or another override to change this, I'm not sure what you're going to be able to do about it...